# how to make java class in downloaded project and its r.java file

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

i have downloaded a android project and needed to add new java classes in it. But there were errors and no r.java file was created when i tried creating a java class. I m working on adt.
i have tried making a package in which java file was created and made an xml file in layout folder. but it showed error in setContentView line

Answer (score 0):

R isn't created if there are any errors in your Sourcecode or XML-Files or if you got missing dependencies. So don't worry about R as long as you haven't fixed the rest.

Could you please post the failing parts of your code? If all the Android-specific code isn't recogniced, try to set a build target (Right-click on your project in Package-Explorer, select Properties->Android->Project Build Tagret) and clean your project (Project->Clean...).